# Collapsing Table Row When Using TBody and JQuery Sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

This isn't your standard usage of JQuery UI's Sortable. Instead of sorting table rows, I am sorting **tbody** tags, which moves multiple rows at once. When you are moving a set of rows, the column widths of the rows collapse. Normally you would use a helper to maintain the column widths... however the standard one does not work in this case.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/md9qwgcb/4/).

You can see the widths collapse when moving the tbody selection.

Here is the code that would normally work with individual rows for the helper, but does not work for a tbody with rows.

```
$('table').sortable({
    cursor: 'move',
    items: 'tbody',
    helper: function(e, ui) {
        ui.children().each(function() {
            $(this).width($(this).width());
        });
        return ui;
    },
    forcePlaceholderSize: true, 
    placeholder: 'placeholder'
});
```

Can someone help come up with a helper that maintains widths when using with a Tbody tag?

Answer (score 3):

Don't ask me why, but jQuery removes `display: table;` on the `<tr>` element and replaces it with `display: block;`. Hence your collapsing width. Just use the helper class added by jQuery UI to the table while its being dragged to change that display back.

```
.ui-sortable-helper tr {
    display:table;
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: That works! Thanks! Though might add another weird behavior with a staggered column "x, y" seen here: [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/md9qwgcb/6/)

EDIT: It also doesn't maintain the widths of the individual cells though. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: Unfortunately after further testing, this does not solve all the problems. Here is a screenshot of an implementation. Note that the columns don't maintain their widths, and the colspan=3 cell collapses down to its smallest width. [imgur album](http://imgur.com/a/KAZpG)

Comment: Can you provide *that* markup? I'm not sure I can help without working with the same stuff you are.